# Error when using data conversion in only one column SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl

I have an XML source that contains a column for [Cellphone] which is basically a 10 digits phone number, im using data conversion to convert this column to varchar(50) to match what I have on the table but i get this error whenever I run the package.

> [Data Conversion 1 [136]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting column "CO-CellPhone" (763) to column "Copy of CO-CellPhone" (234).  The conversion returned status value 6 and status text "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".

> [Data Conversion 1 [136]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.

> The "Data Conversion 1.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Copy of CO-CellPhone]" failed because error code 0xC0209082 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion 1.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Copy of CO-CellPhone]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

I tried to change it to integer but it didn't work, I checked the XML source and this is the value

```
<CO-CellPhone>4855895687</CO-CellPhone>
```

This is dummy data by the way :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: The value shown is obviously going to fit into a `varchar(50)` (even if the tags are getting picked up), so there's something amiss with the conversion. Without seeing the conversion task, and the data flow, it's hard to say what, though. Have you tried putting a data viewer ahead of the conversion to check your inputs?

Comment: In addition to @EricBrandt excellent debugging advice, add an error output path from the Data Viewer to ... anything and add your data viewer on that path as well as this will light up with whatever is wrong.

Comment: @billinkc . @ EricBrandt 
Thank you guys for the input, I added the data viewer and since it fails at the data conversion task, the package execution will stop and I don't see what happens with the package. I uploaded the requested screenshots below, I hope it will make things clearer
[link]https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CwxGzB5_EXB0eVe6kYzqlcJj86Gip6zC?usp=sharing[link]

Comment: What about leading spaces? Can you trim those?